# Disabling ReSharper reordering of code during code reformatting?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I use the code reformatting tool in ReSharper to get some standard format on my code, but I don't like that it moves methods around.

For instance if I rename a method, and then reformat, the method is moved. This makes merging changes between branches a nightmare.

Is there any setting I have missed that will disable this particular part of the reformatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the Type Members Layout xml for that. In that file you have several patterns which you can reorder or delete to get the behaviour you want. All the changes you make in that file will be reflected in the following file:

`C:\Documents and Settings\user\Program Data\JetBrains\ReSharper\v4.5\vs8.0\UserSettings.xml`

so you can make a backup before playing with it or add it to your source code tree.

Comment: Since I have "shared, per solution", that setting was actually stored in the local `SolutionFile.5.1.ReSharper` file so it was under source control, easy to revert. However, I discovered that settings to this file was only saved when I closed the solution. I wonder if I have all the settings in source control that I should. Anyway, thanks for that answer, it was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Set up a custom R# profile

Click Resharper > Tools > Code Cleanup

Then choose "Edit profiles", add a new profile, deselect what you don't want and save it.

Run this profile in the future

Comment: I was hoping there was a setting outside of this, as now I can just do `Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C, Enter` to do a cleanup.

Comment: It doesn't appear that these custom profiles are saved in the shared resharper file that I commit to source control. Is that correct? If so then it doesn't look like it'll be much use to me.

Comment: Don't you have to modify the Type Members Lyout xml for that?

Comment: @yeye: Yes, seems like I have to do that, will experiment a bit with that setting.

Comment: The changes are saved to: C:\Documents and Settings\user\Program Data\JetBrains\ReSharper\v4.5\vs8.0\UserSettings.xml

Comment: @yeye: If you add an answer to this effect, I will accept that. I have specified that the settings should be shared per solution, so the override was saved in the local .ReSharper file, that worked wonders. Ended up just clearing out the whole type layout xml part, except for the start/end tags of the patterns document. This worked and left my renamed methods in place.

Comment: I've always been partial to Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D, Enter. Same results as far as I can tell.